# How can i have Tessaract on Windows?

Tags: windows, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, python-tesseract

I am working on a Text Recognition Solution and I need to use Tesseract on Windows OS.

Is there a command line to know if it's already installed? If not how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

Installer for Windows for Tesseract 3.05 and Tesseract 4 are available from [Tesseract at UB Mannheim](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki). You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki). You need to install it, windows does not come preinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install tesseract using windows installer available [here](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki). Then you should install the python wrapper as:

```
pip install pytesseract
```

Then you should also set the tesseract path in your script after importing pytesseract library as below (Please do not forget that installation path might be modified in your case!):

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
```